# Rails + CanCan + Polymorphic Association not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, cancan, polymorphic-associations

I am trying to get cancan to work with a polymorphic association, i have read through the docs and wiki and am not able to get it working...

I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :areas, :as => :owner, :dependent => :destroy            
end 

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :areas, :as => :owner, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Area < ActiveRecord::Base   
  belongs_to :owner, :polymorphic => true
end
```

and in the controller:

```
class AreasController < ApplicationController  

  load_resource :user, :instance_name => :owner
  load_resource :account, :instance_name => :owner
  load_and_authorize_resource :area, :through => :owner

  before_filter :authorize_parent

  respond_to :html

  def authorize_parent
    authorize! :manage, @owner
  end    

  def index   
  end          

  def show
    @events = @area.events.page(params[:page]).per(5)
    respond_with @area
  end

  def new 
    respond_with @area
  end               

  def create                                
    @area = @owner.areas.new(params[:area])   
    if @area.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your new area has been created..."
    end  
    respond_with @area
  end

end
```

and the following abilities:

```
  can :manage, Area, :owner => { :memberships => { :user => { :id => user.id } } } # Accounts through Membership     
  can :manage, Area, :owner => { :id => user.id } # User
```

the new and create actions work great for both user_areas and account_areas but when i try to go to the index action of areas i get the following error:

```
NameError in AreasController#index

uninitialized constant Owner
```

Any thoughts? many thanks

Comment: can you paste your controller code?

Comment: sorry that was a bit of an oversight...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It considers that your class is called `Owner`, maybe you can try like:

```
load_resource :user, :instance_name => :owner, :class=>'User'
load_resource :account, :instance_name => :owner, :class=>'Account'
load_and_authorize_resource :area, :through => :owner
```

If dont works, see if this issue solves your problem: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/73

Based on the ticket if you are using 1.3 or later version then you can do the following:

```
load_resource :user
load_resource :account
load_and_authorize_resource :area, :through => [:user, :account]
```

But in this case your `authorize_parent` method changes like this:

```
def authorize_parent
  authorize! :manage, (@user||@account)
end
```

For detailed documentation please see the title `Polymorphic associations` on : https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Nested-Resources

Let me know if works for you. Cheers Andy ;)